# How to change or remove splash screen in windows 8.1?

Tags: c#, windows-8.1

I am working on windows 8.1 app and I found that it contains default splash screen which we can't remove. Is there a way we can remove it something similar to windows phone 8. I want a splash screen which loads until a particular process is completed (example zip extraction,editing resources etc). I also did some research and found that *Extended Splash Screen* will help but if  I add a progress ring, people using the app will know the difference that there are two screens. Please anyone suggest what will be the best approach?

Comment: I believe in the manifest you can set the splash screen

Comment: do you have the source code to the windows 8 app..if so why can't you comment out the code and and your own extension methods, functions and or procedures to do what you need it to do..?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to go to the Package.manifest, through Visual Studio, and change the splash screen value.  Here is a [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh973049.aspx) to the Xaml version and the steps:

1. Open your app in Visual Studio 2013.
2. From Solution Explorer, open the "Package.appxmanifest".
3. Open the Visual Assets tab, select Splash Screen and you'll see the "Assets\SplashScreen.png" path in the Splash Screen field which you can change to whatever you want.

Then you can use the [Extend Splash Screen](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh868191.aspx) functionality to continue the screen until your app is ready.

Comment: Thanks but can I redirect to from extended splash screen to different page, or it is mandatory to navigate to *MainPage.xaml* ?

Comment: That is a different question, but fortunately they covered it in this [SO post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21343833/navigate-from-extended-splash-screen-when-app-is-loaded?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

The splash screen is an image in the root folder of the project. you can edit it in any image editor.

While you cannot remove the splashscreen, one option is to use a screen shot of your main page as a splashscreen, this way giving the impression that the app starts quickly.

Answer (score 1):

In your Visual Studio Solution, Right click "package.phone.appxmanifest" --> View Code and comment this line: `<m3:SplashScreen Image="images\SplashScreenPhone.png" />` . And the default splashscreen in windows app will be removed. Note: Manifest file name might defer for phone and windows app.